# WebAPI controller. How to add dynamic methods?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, multiple-inheritance

I need to be able to serve additional methods in my generic controller if controller implements specific interface or has additional attribute or something like that. Here is what I have right now:

```
public abstract class AnimalController
{
    [HttpPost]
    public void Walk() { }
}

public class DogController : AnimalController
{
    [HttpPost]
    public void Bark() { }
}

public class CatController : AnimalController
{
    [HttpPost]
    public void Mew() { }
}

public class MutantController : DogController
{
    [HttpPost]
    public void Mew() { }
}
```

`Mutant` should have abilities of both `Dog` and `Cat`, but C# does not allow to do

```
public class MutantController : DogController, CatController
{
}
```

I was wondering what is the best way to solve this in context of WebAPI? Essentialy I need to add additional web methods depending on certain abilities. One solution is to do something like this:

```
public abstract class AnimalController
{
    [HttpPost]
    public void Walk() { }
}

public class DogController : AnimalController, ICanBark
{
    [HttpPost]
    public void Bark() { }
}

public class CatController : AnimalController, ICanMew
{
    [HttpPost]
    public void Mew() { }
}

public class MutantController : AnimalController, ICanMew, ICanBark
{
    [HttpPost]
    public void Bark() { }

    [HttpPost]
    public void Mew() { }
}
```

This will result in lots of additional code. I was thinking maybe SOMEHOW add methods dynamically so WebAPI knows to use additional controller when I place attributes on main one? Or processes via methods on attribute?

```
[CanMew]
[CanBark]
public class MutantController : AnimalController
{
}
```

Comment: This is easier if as much of the logic as possible is removed from the controllers. Some other class or classes are injected into the controller, and the only purpose of the controller is to receive the request and delegate it to the "real" class that handles it. Now it doesn't matter as much if you add extra methods to your controllers because you're not duplicating as much code. A side effect is that more of your code is decoupled from the controller, which means it's easier to unit test and use separately from a web application.

Comment: @ScottHannen Yes. With services and interfaces I can do that. But I will have dozens of controllers with dozens of methods which will wrap service calls. Adding additional "ability" to Cat will require copy/paste to all controllers

Comment: Could you accomplish it with routing, so that all requests for certain actions go to the same controller? That way there would only be one of each method, but from the routes it would appear that they were going to different controllers. Is that in line with what you're trying to do? It's not totally clear. If the methods are different then repeating them wouldn't be code duplication. But if they're all the same then code duplication is inevitable unless you have some inheritance hierarchy (with the complications that it could entail.)

Comment: Use a filter.  If you are .NET Framework (ActionFilter) and .NET Core (ServiceFilter). Inject a bool or Emum and respond accordingly.